# What is best way to implement Dynamic URL Routing using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have a large application and one of our requirement is dynamic views need to be shown to user from a links in Grid. We are using kendo grid to display data.

e.g. clicking on customer name should launch customer view at run time below grid, so user can update it's data.

I am not sure how to invoke dynamic views using $urlRouterProvider, We are currently using angular but it only allows single view.

Comment: I'd check out [$stateParams Service](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) and [Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#nested-states--views)

Answer (score 0):

The best what you can do, is to check the functionality of the *ui-router* demo application: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1. See how the *Detail* is changing while selecting different *Items* in the *List view*.

The full sample code could be downloaded here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/sample.

And the best explanation *(except the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference))* is the **[state.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/states.js)** - full and detail description how the demo is working.